# Android приложение: долгий переход на следующую активность

Tags: android, activity, activity-life-cycle

Привет. Я заметил неприятную вещь - очень медленная реакция на кнопку, которая открывает новую активити. Мне казалось, что где-то полсекунды, а когда промерил, оказалось от 0,5 для пустой формы до 5 секунд для окна насыщенного элементами!

Для точности замеров я отключил анимации в системе через меню для разработчиков.
Вот, что вышло для формы с четырьмя кнопками:

- +150мс - касание и первый вызов onUserIteraction - startActivity(intent);
- +200мс - команда - onPause текущей активити.
- +100мс - onPause - начало onCreate следующей активити.
- +200мс - длительность super.onCreate()
- +100мс - длительность setContentView().
- +80мс - setContentView - onAttachedToWindow - это происходит, когда всё сформировано, наполнено, прорисовано и передано в распоряжение
  системе.
- +1150мс - onAttachedToWindow - onStop()

  **2с - ОБЩЕЕ время!**

Если загрузить форму посильнее, то в какой-то момент экран просто чёрный на некоторое время.

Моя единственная идея - пока показывается текущая форма, в фоне создавать все следующие, чтобы они уже были в оперативке готовые и остановленные, чтобы их оставалось только подредактировать данные полей и стартануть, и визуально они открывались сразу, без фризов и чёрных экранов. *Это возможно?*

Comment: А в активити происходят какие-нибудь действия, рассчеты? Можете показать скрин? (просто интересно)

Comment: android не создает другие "формы" заранее, пока они не на переднем плане

Comment: Нет, я создал простое тестовое приложение. Там нечего показывать - просто кнопка вызывающая следующее активити. Между делом происходит только System.currentTimeMillis(), запись и передача в extar только времени в переменной long.

Comment: @pavlofff, а что делать, если имеется только одно ядро 600MHz? Ожидание реальных наполненных активити просто невозможно долгое. Приходится даже откладывать паузами в фоне любую деятельность, пока вызываемая активность не станет доступной пользователю, на это уходит до 5 секунд.

Comment: Абсолютно правильная стратегия. При старте сделать минимум, затем, уже после появления перед пользователем дозагружать данные и инициализировать элементы. Возьмите профайлер и посмотрите, кто сожрал процессор.

Answer (score 1):

Во первых Вам нужно разобраться с наложениями - каждое нежелательное наложение элементов друг на друга затормаживает приложение т.к. телефон прорисовывает то что не видно глазу и тратит на это ресурсы. Например Вы говорите что у Вас 4ре кнопки, если это ImageButton и они закрывают весть экран то фон вам не виден, чтобы телефон его не прогружал достаточно в классе данной активности написать:

```
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(null);
```

В разметке layout убедитесь что не устанавливаете лишний background.
Также если у Вас ImageButton то установку изображений лучше всего производить из класса с помощью библиотек [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) или [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide). На мой взгляд glide лучше справляется с задачей.